# Query regarding allowed characters for Excel names

Tags: excel

I have a workbook that makes extensive use of Names for specific cells and areas.  I have had no problem using names such as `DOD3.4x24`, `DOD3.4x24_PC` and `DOD3.Mx2_PC`.  However, when I try to use the names `DOD3.Mx2` or `DOD3.Mx3` I get a syntax error saying the name is incorrect.  I don't understand why as these names don't appear to contravene Excel's naming convention and do not already exist.  Any ideas?

Comment: It has to do with Excel recognizing `DOD3` and `MX2` as cell references. Why it does so when seperated by a dot I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Both `:` and `.` can be used as the range operator (Excel will convert the dot into a colon in a formula). So A1.B3 and A1:B3 are equivalent. That's why it doesn't like two apparent cell addresses either side of a dot.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the dot @Rory =). To OP: You'll now notice that `DOD3.XFE7` is valid.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.